# Can't read csv(Tab delimited) properly

Tags: php

I have simple csv file which is tab delimited which i have to use as it is because it is coming from somewhere and i hvae to read it and insert it into my db i have used a simple php code to read it

```
if(($handle = fopen("var/import/MMT29DEC.csv","r"))!==FALSE){
            /*Skip the first row*/
            fgetcsv($handle, 1000,chr(9));
            while(($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,chr(9)))!==FALSE){
                    print_r($data[0]);
                        }
}
```

When print_r the data it shows like

```
Array ( [0] => 01SATAPC [1] => 40ATAPC [2] => [3] => 21P [4] => SERIAL ATA POWER CABLE [5] => 0.00 [6] => 2.00 [7] => 0 [8] => Power Supplies [9] => SERIAL ATA POWER CABLE [10] =>
4 TO 15 PIN 160MM
[11] => [12] => [13] => [14] => MELBHO [15] => 0.000 [16] => [17] => Order to Order [18] => 4 [19] => 2013-01-18 )
```

Which is the desired result but when i go to access the particular column value using the $data['index'] e.g. $data[8] or $data[1] it weirdly giving me garbage values says for some iterations it give me right values but after 10-15 rows its starting giving me the some numbers and  other column values..... i don't know whats is going on with this as far as i  know it should be formatting issue i have tried open the file in excel and its coming fine....

Comment: Have a look at the lines, where you get the unwanted results. Are they probably formatted?

Comment: @KingCrunch nope they seems fine... even the $data array is coming fine then why is not giving the proper index value :'(

Comment: both should be same, but just give a try. use "\t" instead of char(9).

Comment: @Venu '\t' not worked...

Comment: @ravisoni are you sure that the second parameter to fgetcsv of 1000 is longer than the longest line in your file? Try setting it to 0 as the docs say [http://php.net/fgetcsv] and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: You rocks @toneplex you got it...

Comment: @ravisoni I've converted my comment to an answer. Could you please accept it, so I can get credit for the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@ravisoni are you sure that the second parameter to fgetcsv of 1000 is longer than the longest line in your file? Try setting it to 0 as the docs say [php.net/fgetcsv] and see if that makes a difference.

```
if(($handle = fopen("var/import/MMT29DEC.csv","r"))!==FALSE){
            /*Skip the first row*/
            fgetcsv($handle, 0,chr(9));
            while(($data = fgetcsv($handle,0,chr(9)))!==FALSE){
                    print_r($data[0]);
                        }
}
```